# Android studio gradle error, facet

Tags: android

I upgraded android studio on Debian and I deleted all the gradle file in the android studio folder. I then got this error:

```
Plugin Error
            Problems found loading plugins:
            Plugin "Google Cloud Tools Core" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle" not installed.
            Plugin "Android Support" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle" not installed.
            Plugin "Android Games" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle" not installed.
            Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle" not installed.
            Plugin "Android APK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle" not installed.
            Plugin "Google Developers Samples" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle" not installed.
            Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle" not installed.
            Plugin "Test Recorder" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle" not installed.
            Plugin "Firebase Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.... (show balloon)

10:18 AM    Error Loading Project: Cannot load 3 facets Details...
```

How can I fix my project?

Answer (score 10):

Go to 
Setting > Plugins 
and then check on the "Android Support"
after that uncheck "Android APK Support"
After that press OK
Android Studio will restart and then again check the "Android APK Support" from Plugins
Android Studio will restart again
Problem Solved !!

Comment: Thanks man, one last thing to do was "Invalidate the caches/restart".

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > Plugins and install all required plugins in your studio.

Comment: when i get to setting, those plugins are checked but the are in red color and i unchecked them then i check again and it bring thes info
    Unable to apply changes: plugins "Android APK Support", "Android Games", "Google Services", "Android Support", "Firebase Services", "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio", "App Links Assistant", "Firebase Testing", "Test Recorder", "Google Developers Samples", "Firebase App Indexing", "Android NDK Support", "Google Cloud Tools Core" won't be able to load.

Answer (score 0):

it's now working perfectly, all i did was to rebuild the project and make sure that gradle is available in the plugins folder